# Render a react component in a new window floating inside the page

Tags: reactjs, jitsi, jitsi-meet

The idea is that the video of the call (jitsi) is above the components of the screen and that I can make a call to the picture-in-picture of the screen of this video, so that the user can browse the page and will not lose visibility of the video with the call currently taking place. This component that you indicated did not work, I used react-draggable (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable#draggable-usage) and it did the first part which is to stay on top of the components and I can move it around on the screen. However, I'm still not able to use PiP by React with this Jitsi iFrame API (https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe). But I believe it is possible, because I installed a chrome extension that was developed by google called Picture-in-Picture extension By Google, and he can take the video and leave it superimposed on the screen without losing its focus. I tried to use the code for this extension (https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/picture-in-picture-chrome-extension/blob/master/src/script.js) but without success yet. If anyone has done something like this and can help me I would be immensely grateful. Thank you all in advance.

[image: Example of my test page]

Comment: What specifically are you needing help with? Just having an element sit "on top" of other elements? Look into absolute position and z-index to get started.

Comment: I wil rewrite my doubt. Thanks